# MVC4 Bundle result to an specific url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

In the **BundleConfig.cs** :

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Will return:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=JHUWR5W7EWq4jk2bzc7kOMHo1HjfQzSHOs8_Vrwy3vc1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I would like to add a domain name to the output :

```
<link href="http://cdn.mydomain.com/Content/css?v=JHUWR5W7EWq4jk2bzc7kOMHo1HjfQzSHOs8_Vrwy3vc1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I can add it manually but i m afarid that the key **JHUWR5W7EWq4jk2bzc7kOMHo1HjfQzSHOs8_Vrwy3vc1** will change.

Is there a way to add a domain name to the bundle output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to call the bundle in the layout with : ***BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl()***

```
<link href="http://cdn.mydomain.com@(BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/css"))" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of

```
@Styles.Render("~/css")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you 
define your bundle away that they aren't stepping on toes. Then when you feel comfortable with a library, use it.